# Problem with simulate space key press in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

i'm working on WFP application where I am using webview2 to show customers a questionnaire. I have a problem with simulate pressing space key via script. I need that, because of protection from sending empty input box when sending questionnaire and the press key event was releasing the lock on the input when pasting text. Previously i used standard WPF webbrowser and i use that script `document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'Space'}));` that works. Now nothing happen when i execute that script.Previous working function:

```
private void SymulateKeyboardKeyPressScript()
        {
            dynamic document = browser.Document;
            dynamic script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = @"text/javascript";
            script.text = @"document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'Space'}));";
            document.Body.appendChild(script);
        }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjxdI.png)
keydown is done, but nothing chang in inputbox.Value has not been changed, field is still empty and the form cannot be submitted.

I hope you could help me with this problem.

Comment: Have you tried preventing the form from submitting if the text box is empty? Or handling validation on the backend differently so that empty strings don't cause exceptions?

Comment: I have to break protection of microsoft forms, MS forms detected input box as empty after sending my text to this input box. I need to simulate keyboard press in this input box.

Comment: Here is my last working script:  document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].focus(); // i'm set focus on first input element in form
document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'Space'})); // simulate press key on keyboard to to break protection of microsoft forms (Required field)
document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value =" + Clipboard.GetText() + "; // paste value to input box